# Spotify error: Can’t play curent track

Tags: spotify

One day the Spotify desktop client for Mac was unable to play my music and kept giving me the error “Can’t play curent track” at the top. I didn't change any preferences, login ID, or anything like that. My phone app still works. I didn't do any major OS upgrades.

How do I get my music to play again?

Comment: What troubleshooting have you tried? Did you re-install Spotify? Is there a specific error code?

Comment: I see in windows showing as no track available. You can import that music if saved in your settings.

Comment: Having a similar issue. After 7 seconds, some tracks fail to play with the dreaded "Can’t play curent track".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found a site that has a solution. Worked for me. I used to be a premium user and now I'm not anymore. I had "high quality streaming" checked in my preferences. Since it's only a premium user's feature, Spotify would say it couldn't play tracks every onces in a while (potentially becuase the software thought I was trying to hear it in a quality I wasn't paying for). Unchecking it fixed it.

Check the post [here](http://dylanvslife.com/2014/10/30/cant-play-the-current-track-spotify-issue-fix/)

Comment: Thanks, I also found a little bit more information here: http://anonymoustechblog.wordpress.com/2014/11/03/spotify-error-cant-play-curent-track/

Answer (score 0):

I have to restart my mac to make Spotify work.
Yes, we are still in the early 21st century. Computers have to be restarted frequently to make it work.